# Double use of future tense after "I hope that"

Tags: tenses, expression-choice, future

I was wondering whether it was correct to use "will" twice in the following sentence:

> I hope that 2016 will be the year I will get to travel.

Using the present tense in the second half of the sentence sounds more natural to me:

> I hope that 2016 will be the year I get to travel.

Also, my understanding is that the first "will" (after "I hope") is not mandatory and that the present tense can be used instead. So, it could also read as "I hope that 2016 is the year I get to travel".

Finally, would "I hope that 2016 is the year I will get to travel" be correct ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And don't neglect, "I hope 2016 is the year I get to travel"! (I'm only playing with you a bit.) Each of your sentences is correct, each in its own way. That is one of the marvels of the English language; it's very flexible. As a friend of mine says of how to get something done with Microsoft Word (for example), "There are any number of ways to accomplish the same thing. Some ways take longer than others but they give you the same result." So it is with expressing a thought in English. So, free yourself up a bit and see how many different ways you can communicate the same basic thought. Don

Comment: @Ricky: Safe to say we're not on the same page, so to speak. IOW, I'm not following you; I'm not pickin' up what you're layin' down; I'm confused. And no, I don't live near Philly. I'm on the other side of the state in Pittsburgh and have been for 32 years. My email address is in my biography page, by the way, so feel free to write. Don

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence sounds more natural, yes. If you want to be more technical, it is also slightly better, grammatically.

It has to do with the 'qualifying' of the word 'year'.

e.g. The year 'of the flood' tells you more about the year by using an adjectival phrase.

The year 'I get to travel' does a similar thing. It puts a label, of sorts, on the year, and you don't really need the 'will'.

Your second sentence is really expressing the hope that 2016  'will be' that year.